# Using a python package

Tags: python, package, ubuntu-16.04

I have downloaded the tar file of the [Python geohash package](https://github.com/vinsci/geohash/)

I import functions from this package to use them inside my python programs. It works completely fine, but only inside its own folder, where it is extracted.

If I intend to use this package in any other location, it doesn't simply import that package.

What should I do if I want to use it anywhere in my system ?
(the package is only available through this tarfile, not through pip/sudo apt-get)

Comment: Also you should take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Geohash/

Answer (score 0):

Simply untar/unzip the file and make sure you have `setup.py` visible. From you command prompt in windows or linux. Go to the dir of the package which you just unzipped/untarred and dir/ls to make sure that `setup.py` is there and then do the following:

If you are using virtualenv:
`/path-to-your-venv/venv/bin/python setup.py install`

If you are not using virtualenv
`python setup.py install`